# Uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'body' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I am having a hard time figuring out why I am getting this error. I made sure that the JavaScript is loaded after the html is, I have even tried replacing this.doc and this.win with just document and window and it has not changed the result. Here is the code I am working with. It is implemented in `<head>` through `<script src="window.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` (I have also tried it at the end of the doc)

```
Window = function(doc, win)
{
    this.doc = doc;
    this.win = win;
    
    this.resize();
    this.win.addEventListener('resize', this.resize);
}

Window.prototype = 
{
    resize: function()
    {
        this.doc.body.innerHTML = window.innerHeight;
    }
};

window.onload = new Window(document, window);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `this` isn't the `Window` object when the callback is called but the global object (`window`). A solution would be to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function :

```
this.win.addEventListener('resize', this.resize.bind(this));
```

If you really need to be compatible with IE8, do this :

```
var _this = this;
this.win.addEventListener('resize', function(){_this.resize() });
```

But your global construct raises alarms. Be careful not to build useless verbose classes "java-style". Do you really need this `Window` class ?

Comment: I am using this class as a test case. I understand this all seems really pointless but it is just a small building block. Thank you very much for your help! I just have to wait to accept your answer